# New transaction is not allowed because there are other threads running in the session LINQ To Entity

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities

Any ideas on why this could be breaking?

```
foreach (var p in pp)
{
    ProjectFiles projectFile = (ProjectFiles)p;
    projectFile.Status = Constants.ProjectFiles_ERROR;
    projectFile.DateLastUpdated = DateTime.Now;
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

I read that the workaround the issue, is to retrieve the results in one go before the foreach loop.

But didnt I do that? "pp" is the collection of results in my case

Comment: Is `pp` the result of a linq query? If so, you may need to do a `ToList()` on it to disconnect it from the database before running your loop.

Comment: call save changes outside loop

Comment: Just a little pointer here. The recommended fix probably works by stopping EF from constantly starting new transactions on each save. However, it points to an issue in EF. The logic here is probably not right. You should start a transaction before saving in a loop, and then commit all, or rollback all at the end. Unless of course this is not the desired logic.

Answer (score 377, accepted):

The `pp` variable isn't a collection of objects, it's an enumerator that can return objects. While you use the enumerator, the source has to remain open.

Use the `ToList` method to realise the enumerator into a collection. That will read all items from the enumerator and close the connection to the source, so that you can use the connection for other things.

```
foreach (var p in pp.ToList())
```

Comment: God bless you @Guffa !!! +1

Comment: Great!! It also works with pp.ToArray()

Comment: Ricardo, it works as long as it is not IQueryable

Comment: @Guffa I had the exact same problem and this simple addition worked for me! Thank you!

Comment: It should be noted that this problem is not specific to Entity Framework. It is related to the underlying SQL Server SqlConnection object. Evidently, in this scenario, Entity framework sees fit to start a transaction for each save. This is a terrible idea, and an argument for not using Entity Framework. My guess is that the code should either commit all changes, or roll them back. This code should be wrapped in a single transaction to achieve this. EF is hiding the transaction handling.

Answer (score 10):

A way to get around this is to call `.ToList()` on your collection before iterating it.

And while you're at it, call `context.SaveChanges()` only once after the loop exits to speed up the code.

Comment: This statement does not seem to describe the real situation, based on the accepted solution's assertions, and those provided in the other answered question, which is linked at the top of this one.  It seems more a case of trying to do the change saving before the iteration is complete, rather than the use of multiple connections

Comment: Yeah, there are not multiple connections going on. It has to do with reading from a connection while at the same time trying to write on it.

Comment: But what if I'm iterating on a million items, I can't load them all into memory. There has to be a way to make updates while also iterating still.

Comment: ORM's aren't the way to update millions of records. They are meant for populating complex objects and maybe a bit of CRUD, but bulk operations should be performed directly on the database or at least via a library specifically meant for bulk operations.

Comment: If you can perform a bulk operation via a stored procedure or scheduled job, then you should ideally want to do that instead.