# Entity Framework 4.1 Context in Extension Method

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4.1, extension-methods

When I run this code it says that:

```
Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected number of rows (0). Entities may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded. Refresh ObjectStateManager entries.
```

I can imagine the situation here. Probably because of this:

```
//Default.aspx.cs
MyEntity cont = new MyEntity();
IEnumerable<Product> p = from c in cont.Products.AsEnumerable()
                select c;
Product example = p.ToArray()[0];
example.Delete(); // This Delete method is an extension method which you'll see in below.
//I also have some other stuff like

IEnumerable<Category> cc = from n in cont.Categories.AsEnumerable()
                                 select n;
cont.Categories.Remove(cc.ToArray()[0]);
cont.SaveChanges(); //throws the error
```

Here is the main part of the extension method

```
public static bool Delete(this Product pro,bool SetNull = false) {
    using (var en = new MyEntity()) {
        IEnumerable<Product> s = from ss in en.Products
                                where ss.ID == pro.ID
                                select ss;

        en.Products.Remove(s.SingleOrDefault());
        en.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

The extension methods works, the entity removes from db. But when the program comes to the

```
cont.SaveChanges();
```

line , it throws the error. I assume, this error comes up because i've changed the entities within some another method using another MyEntity() class. So i've searched to find a way to refresh the other one. But i couldn't ...

Comment: I'm curious to know - did my answer solve your problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you should pass the context as a parameter to the delete method.
Do not construct a new context in the method, and delete from it - delete from the original context instead.

Comment: `New transaction is not allowed because there are other threads running in the session.`

This time , this error comes up...

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out by usign omer schleifer's advice and also something i found on another topic.

[New transaction is not allowed because there are other threads running in the session LINQ To Entity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10096509/new-transaction-is-not-allowed-because-there-are-other-threads-running-in-the-se)

I used the context as a parameter in delete method but it thrown an error

```
New transaction is not allowed because there are other threads running in the session
```

And then i changed the for loop that i use,  like this

```
foreach (Product m in p.ToList())
{
}
```

instead of this

```
foreach (Product m in p)
{
}
```

and problem has resolved.

Thank you for your answers...