# New transaction is not allowed because there are other threads running in the session - mvc

Tags: multithreading, asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller

I just performing Insert and Read operation using EF with SP. I've two SP, one for read and another for Inserting. When I execute this operation one by one, I am getting this error on second SP

> New transaction is not allowed because there are other threads running in the session.

Code

```
var students = db.GetStudentByID(1);

Student_Mast model = new Student_Mast();
model.First_Name = "John";
model.Last_Name = "Abraham";
model.Roll_No = 2;
db.Student_Mast.Add(model);
db.SaveChanges();
```

I've checked many post, but all refering to foreach loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The students variable isn't a collection of objects, it's an enumerator that can return objects. While you use the enumerator, the source has to remain open.

```
var students = db.GetStudentByID(1).ToList();
```

Please refer this link for the brief.
[go here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10096509/new-transaction-is-not-allowed-because-there-are-other-threads-running-in-the-se)